# Issue with reading from CSV

Tags: python, csv, class, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to read from file. Everything works, but I got the key error in spite of the fact that they key exist in debugger. I saw very similiar codes working but I don't have any idea why I got `KeyError` when I reach `"id_samolotu"`. My code:

```
import csv
from lot import DatabaseofLoty, Lot

def read_from_csv(path):
    loty = []
    with open(path,"r") as file_handle:
        reader = csv.DictReader(file_handle)
        for row in reader:
            numer_lotu = row["numer_lotu"]
            id_samolotu = row["id_samolotu"]
            czas_lotu = row['czas_lotu']
            trasa = row['trasa']
            wolne_miejscaek = row['wolne_miejscaek']
            wolne_miejscabiz = row['wolne_miejscabiz']
            wolne_miejscapr = row['wolne_miejscapr']
            bramka = row['bramka']
            lot = Lot(numer_lotu, id_samolotu, czas_lotu, trasa, wolne_miejscaek,
                      wolne_miejscabiz, wolne_miejscapr, bramka)
            loty.append(lot)
            database = DatabaseofLoty(loty)

read_from_csv("loty.txt")
```

`loty.txt` file:

```
numer_lotu, id_samolotu, czas_lotu, trasa, wolne_miejscaek, wolne_miejscabiz, wolne_miejscpr, bramka
1, 3, 3:52, Amsterdam-Berlin, 129, 92, 192, 8
```

Comment: It looks like the delimiters of your CSV file have and extra space following them, which is non-standard and would become part of the keys and values in the dictionary `DictReader` returns. You can verify this by printing the value of `row` in the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you. I was thinking that the problem is much more complicated. Thank you :)